# Not finding the code for "Unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface" issue

Tags: android

I am using a lot of libraries in my android app. While submitting I am getting an "Unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface" error in the play store. I have removed "setDefaultHostnameVerifier" from my parent code and re-submitted again but getting the same error. I am using many libraries so not able to get the exact library/class from where this issue is generating. What is the way to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Using various websites you can scan your app. I scanned my application from this website and got the exact class: https://www.immuniweb.com/mobile